# How to restrict indirect access to the user for the table through views or procedures?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the SSMS

- I created a login `log_a`
- I created a database `test_db`
- I created a user `log_u` for login `log_a` in database `test_db`
- I created 4 tables `t1, t2, t3, t4`

I provide `select` permission on table `t1` and `t2` to user `log_u`.
`log_u` don't have permissions on tables `t3` and `t4`.

But user `log_u` is able to access the data of the tables `t3` and `t4` through views and procedures.

I don't want to restrict or deny the select or execute permission to the user on the view and procedures but even if they have select or execute permission on the views and procedures, I want to restrict the users from accessing those tables indirectly using views and procedures.

I tried using alter authorization it alter the permissions of other over and deny them from accessing the view and procedures.

I tried using restrict and denying tables and columns but it user still can access the indirectly through views and procedures.

Comment: Why *don't you* want to restrict the user to use a view that referenses a table you don't want them to access?

Comment: If all you did was create user `log_u` and grant select to two tables, then `log_u` does *not* have permission to execute stored procedures or select from any views, because you didn't grant those permissions to `log_u`. In other words, more has happened than your question indicates. Is `log_u` the owner of the schema containing these additional objects? Are they a member of any database roles? Is log_a a member of any server roles?

Comment: In response to _if they have select or execute permission on the views and procedures, I want to restrict the users from accessing those tables indirectly using views and procedures_: if those views and procedures, and the underlying tables, are in the same schema, or are in schemas owned by the same user, then [ownership chaining](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6394/understanding-sql-server-ownership-chaining/) implicitly grants permission to the underlying table. You would have to create the objects in different schemas (with different owners).

Comment: My manager wants things to be that way, so I don't want to restrict them. I did as he asked me to. That was also my initial thought. I mentioned it to him, but he declined. What we want is for the user to be restricted from anywhere, even if user have select permission on the view or processes, if user do not have select permission to the table. @siggemannen

Comment: Sounds dumb to be honest. I don't think it's possible as that's how rights work in sql server. It's like wanting to change the laws of physics. Maybe the manager knows some trick on how to do it though

Comment: It's worse... it's like saying you want ice cream and also you don't want ice cream! If view V selects from table T, *what would it even mean* to say "As the owner of both V and T, I grant select permission on V, but I don't want the user to see data from T"? I think you need to get more detailed requirements from your manager and then come back to us.

Comment: He has already told me that this is our desired outcome!! Unless users have the SELECT permission for the table, we do not want users to be able to access the tables from anywhere. This implies that even in cases when a user is authorized to select data from the view or has execute permission over the procedure. He can't be more specific than this. :) @allmhuran

Comment: After doing some research on this topic, I've discovered that SQL server  doesn't work the way we'd like it to. Nevertheless, there may be a means by which we might accomplish our intended result. We might be able to achieve this in some way. I have already looked into seeing whether there is a setting or permission in SQL Server that could allow this, and the answer is clearly no. That is something I know. As a result, I'm asking here to see if this has been accomplished by anyone. It's possible that someone used triggers or another method to achieve it. @siggemannen

Comment: I guess what you can do is implement row level security on the tables in question. This would still allow use to access the table itself, but he will get no data back. This is of course extremely convuleted way of doing this. Why can't you just disallow the access to stored procedures / views?

Comment: OK, if the requirements are exactly as you have stated - you haven't misunderstood them in any way - then the requirement is simply nonsensical. Suppose I had a big safe, and then a smaller safe outside the big safe. I use the small safe to store the key to the big safe. Then I say "I want you to give someone the key to the small safe, but without giving them the ability to open the big safe". Do you see that this is silly? Link your manager to this comment thread.